# MatPlotLib rotate 3D plot around fixed axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I am trying to rotate the following figure around the vertical green axis drawn:

[image: Rotate around vertical Green axis]

However, I'm running into trouble trying to set the correct elevation and azimuthal values in order to correctly rotate my figure.

For example,

```
    for i in range(0,360):
        axU.view_init(100-i,-90+i)
        plt.draw()
        plt.savefig('./gif1/rot%i.jpg'%i,dpi=100)
```

gives me a figure like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzMtJ.jpg

and

```
    for i in range(0,360):
        axU.view_init(100,-90+i)
        plt.draw()
        plt.savefig('./gif1/rot%i.jpg'%i,dpi=100)
```

looks something like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyQyb.jpg

both give me too much rotations around unwanted axes, where as I really just want to pan around the green axis drawn above. Is there any way to do this?

```
    for i in range(0,360):
        axU.view_init(100-i,-90)
        plt.draw()
        plt.savefig('./gif1/rot%i.jpg'%i,dpi=100)
```

This give me something similar to what I want, where the rotation is uniform around one axis, but this rotates around the horizontal green axis whereas I would like it to rotate around the vertical green axis.

[rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24PmG.jpg)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/24PmG.jpg

Comment: Be aware that `view_init` does not rotate the plot but sets the camera position. So you will need to ask yourself where the camera needs to be to obtain the desired rotation. A rotation about an axis, which does not go through the middle of the plot is thus not even possible. For anything else, try to parametrize the curve of the camera.

Comment: ok thank you, I shall look into alternatives to get the view I want